# binding not working in vuejs 2.4.4

Tags: data-binding, vue.js

I have several forms element, that I want to retrieve the value and post it.

I will take only one field, that I can't bind with `v-model`

```
<template>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label for="fightDuration">{{ translations.fightDuration }}</label>
    <i class="icon-help" data-popup="tooltip" title="" data-placement="right"
       :data-original-title=translations.fightDurationTooltip></i>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control fightDuration ui-timepicker-input"
               id="fightDuration" name="fightDuration" type="text"
               autocomplete="off"
               v-model="info.fightDuration">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
data() {
        return {
            info: {
                fightDuration: null,
                ... // more fields here     
            }
        }
},
mounted: function () {
    this.info.fightDuration = this.setting.fightDuration;
    ... // more fields here
}
```

When I change fightDuration value in input, field value is not changing, why is it happening???

Comment: How do you know it's not updating? Did you check with the Vue devtools (on chrome) the current state of `info.fightDuration` after you input something?

Comment: yes, I check it with devtools

Comment: I will try to make a fiddle right now